AWS - createCertificateFromCsr - Fail to connect
till now we created a certificate using sdk method IotClient.CreateKeysAndCertificate. And easily manage to connect from the client side with the private key and certificate using iot device sdk
AwsIotMqtt5ClientBuilder.newDirectMqttBuilderWithMtlsFromPath(iotEndpoint, pemCert, pemPrivateKey);

pemCert and pemPrivateKey are the return values from the IotClient.CreateKeysAndCertificate method.
Now we would like to change the certificate creation by creating our own keys and let AWS only create and register our iot certficate calling the method IotClient.createCertificateFromCsr.
We've manage to create the certificate properly using the following code.

// Dependencies 
// 'org.bouncycastle:bc-fips:1.0.2.5'
// 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-fips:1.0.7'
// 'software.amazon.awssdk:iot:2.25.52'

    private KeyPair generateRSAKeyPair(int keySize) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BCFIPS");
        // Initialize the key size
        generator.initialize(keySize);
        // Generate the key pair
        return generator.generateKeyPair();
    }

    private String convertToPemFormat(Object keyOrRequest) throws Exception {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        try (JcaPEMWriter pemWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(stringWriter)) {
            pemWriter.writeObject(keyOrRequest);
        }
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }

// .... Our code 

KeyPair keyPair = generateRSAKeyPair(keySize);

        // create the CSR
        X500Principal subject = new X500Principal(principleName);
        PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder csrBuilder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(subject, keyPair.getPublic());
        JcaContentSignerBuilder csBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA");
        PKCS10CertificationRequest csRequest = csrBuilder.build(csBuilder.build(keyPair.getPrivate()));

        // convert the CSR to PEM format
        String pemCsr = convertToPemFormat(csRequest);

 CreateCertificateFromCsrRequest request = CreateCertificateFromCsrRequest.builder()
                    .certificateSigningRequest(pemCsr)
                    .setAsActive(true)
                    .build();

CreateCertificateFromCsrResponse cert = IotClient.builder().build().createCertificateFromCsr(request);


// On the client side...
// using 'software.amazon.awssdk.iotdevicesdk:aws-iot-device-sdk:1.20.7'

String privateKeyPEM = convertToPemFormat(new PemObject("RSA PRIVATE KEY", keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded()));

AwsIotMqtt5ClientBuilder builder = AwsIotMqtt5ClientBuilder.newDirectMqttBuilderWithMtlsFromMemory(
                        ourIotEndpoint, // This have to be from you AWS IOT environment
                        cert.certificatePem(),
                        privateKeyPEM);

builder.withPort(443L);
Mqtt5Client returnClient = builder.build(); // <- crashing here



The certificate is created well in AWS. It is being attached to the thing and with the needed policies for connection.
We converted our privatekey to PEM as well using the method above.
But when we try to connect in the client side with MQTT we get the following error.
TlsContext.tls_ctx_new: Failed to create new aws_tls_ctx (aws_last_error: AWS_IO_FILE_VALIDATION_FAILURE(1038), A file was read and the input did not match the expected value)..
What do I miss ?

Comment why you Vote -1 would be appreciated.

Have you tried to find out what the difference between pemCert and pemPrivateKey is, on the one hand for the data returned by IotClient.CreateKeysAndCertificate() and on the other hand for the data you create with your custom methods?

In addition, numerous types/methods are undefined, e.g. GuardedString, getIotClient(), CreateCertificateFromCsrRequest etc. so that no repro is possible. And where does BouncyCastleFIPSProviderSingleton come from (I can't find it in bc-fips or bcpkix-fips, possibly from Nimbus Jose +  JWT?), i.e. which BC jars or verisons are you using? Try to convert your code into an MCVE. Without sample data and repro it is hard to analyze.

@Topaco Thanks for the reply. I've fixed my code. Sadly I couldn't create a full running example since it is very much based on AWS environment etc.. I hope something will pop up just from seeing the code.. I suspect it is in the code that convert the private key to PEM. since I've tried to used iotClient.createKeysAndCertficate which returns private and public keys and certificate - all in string PEM format. I've used those keys to generate my CSR request and register a new certificate and the connection was made successfully. so perhaps this is the direction ?

@Topaco regarding the differences of the outputs between the 2 methods. I've done it of course :) Seems that my keys has a few more characters keys then what AWS is creating. But the key is valid.. Tried it online and verified that the key is valid.. and I've read that RSA keys size with the same bit size can have different sizes... So I'm lost

Your PEM encoding of the private RSA key is inconsistent. The body is PKCS#8 formatted, while header/footer of a PKCS#1 formatted key is used. Apply new PemObject("PRIVATE KEY",....

You should compare the data in an ASN.1 parser like https://lapo.it/asn1js/ to see what differences (content, format, etc.) there are, and then you could try to tweak the code to get rid of those differences.

@Topaco genius!!! Your direction was right. I saw a difference using this link u sent and It was the problem. I had to create manually PKCS1 formatted private key.. I will share the answer. Thanks a lot!

The problem was the metadata generated in the PEM file.
AWS expects PCKS1 (and not PCKS8) format and the following converting code is now working.
instead of creating the PEM object like this
bytes[] data = privateKey.getEncoded();
PemObject pemPrivateKey = new PemObject("RSA PRIVATE KEY", data)

We should use this code
RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec keySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(
                                    keyFactory.generatePrivate(
                                    new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey.getEncoded())), SAPrivateCrtKeySpec.class);

byte[] data = new RSAPrivateKey(
                    keySpec.getModulus(),
                    keySpec.getPublicExponent(),
                    keySpec.getPrivateExponent(),
                    keySpec.getPrimeP(),
                    keySpec.getPrimeQ(),
                    keySpec.getPrimeExponentP(),
                    keySpec.getPrimeExponentQ(),
                    keySpec.getCrtCoefficient()
            ).getEncoded();

PemObject pemPrivateKey = new PemObject("RSA PRIVATE KEY", data)

Thanks a lot to @Topaco for the help!
